# Input in a function mixed with input in main

Tags: c, input, switch-statement, scanf

Lets say I have a void function and main func of course.

```
void function() {
    char a, b;
    printf("Enter two chars: ");
    scanf("%c %c", &a, &b);
    // there will be a code that does something with entered chars ...
}

int main() {
    char c;
    while(1) {
        switch(c = getchar()) {
        case 'v':
            function();
            break;
        case 'c':
            someOtherFunc();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is, when I run the program, I press `v`, it calls the `function()` which wants from me 2 characters to input. Okay, I put `x` and `c` and what it does is that it calls another function from the switch which is not correct because I do not want to run another function yet.I need to do something with those 2 chars in first function. It is mixing inputs. How can I solve this? I need to have switch available only if function is 100% done with its job. I have several functions in my program and all of them are void. Suggestions?

Comment: `scanf("%c %c", &a, &b);` --> `scanf(" %c %c", &a, &b);`

Comment: that does not really work for me, it counts that space ..I must enter chars from the beginning of the line..

Comment: `function();` --> `getchar();function();`, then `scanf("%c%c", &a, &b); `

Comment: @BLUEPIXY can you please explain it to me?

Comment: @febeks I think it's because of the buffered I/O. When you enter `v`, it remains a newline in your input buffer. Hence, you have to read it up with an additional `getchar()` before calling the `function()`.

Comment: @febeks , BLUEPIXY tells you to change `function()` to `getchar();function();` and use `scanf("%c%c", &a, &b)` instead of your `scanf`. Changing the latter is not necessary, though

Answer (score 0):

Lets see what is going on in your program, shall we?

Execution reaches

```
switch(c = getchar())
```

and `getchar()` waits for input. You press `v` and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. `getchar()` consumes the `v` and stores it in `c`. `function()` is called.

The `printf` in `function()` prints `"Enter two chars: "` and the execution reaches the `scanf`.

The first `%c` in `scanf` **sees the `\n` character in the input stream and consumes it**. The space between the `%c`s will skip whitespace characters(like `\n`,`' '` etc),if any, until the first non-whitespace character. You enter `xc` and the second `%c` in the `scanf` consumes `x` while `c` is left in the input stream. `function()` exits.

The `break;` in `main` executes and breaks out of the `switch`. The `while` loop begins its next iteration. Execution reaches

```
switch(c = getchar())
```

and `getchar()` **sees the `c` left over by the previous `scanf`** and consumes it and stores it in `c`. `someOtherFunc();` is called.

---

See the fault? The `\n` character spoils it all. As [@BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) [has already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980567/input-in-a-function-mixed-with-input-in-main#comment42495543_26980567) [how to solve the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980567/input-in-a-function-mixed-with-input-in-main#comment42496599_26980567), use a space before the first `%c` of the `scanf` or use a `getchar()` before calling `function()` and `someOtherFunc()` to fix the issue. If you are currently wondering what does the space do, then read my answer once again. I've specified what the space between the `%c`s in your `scanf` does. As for the `getchar()`, it consumes the newline character left over by the `getchar()` inside the `switch` statement.